# Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors с использованием accces list

Tags: apache, nginx

Подскажите, есть ли какая-то возможность задействовать хедер Content-Security-Policy с директивой frame-ancestors используя что-то вроде вложенного acces list-а(что-то похожее на include, upstream и т.п.)

Задача: прятать прописанные, разрешённые в данной директиве Urls и пр.(а их достаточно много планируется)

P.S. Может есть возможность прятать все атрибуты хедера Content-Security-Policy

Comment: Ничего не понял. Что куда и зачем нужно прятать?

Comment: Пример:
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors: 'self' *.site1.com *.site2.com *.site3.com *.site3.com
Тем самым я разрешаю использовать свой ресурс в iframe для перечисленных сайтов
Но я не хочу светить данные сайты(содержание хедера легко посмотреть)
Вопрос: имеется ли возможность задать что-то вида
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors: 'self' acess_url или (include acess_url)
А в acess_url указать разрешённые сайты
Или как-то по иному решить...

Comment: https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/2/#frame-ancestors-multiple-source-values можно проверять referer или какой-нибудь параметр и выставлять только нужный домен